# Resolve LINQ query between WebService and ClientApplication

Tags: c#, linq, web-services, data-binding

Goal: create webservice that will query database and return rows, then pass it to client application and insert into DataGridView.

what I have done:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public IEnumerable<DataRow> getTransactions(int client_id)
    {
        BankDataLINQDataContext DB = new BankDataLINQDataContext();
        IEnumerable<DataRow> query = (from u in DB.Transactions.AsEnumerable() where u.ClientID == client_id select u) as IEnumerable<DataRow>;
        return query;
    }
```

Problem:
1. No error before compile - error occured while i try to compile code.
2. I don't have any idea how to pick up data in Client Application. I tried pass it by List but it didn't work ("No Valid Source).

Please help...

Comment: I think you're looking for a WCF Data Service, but it's hard to tell from your question.

Comment: By DataRow, is that the ADO.NET DataRow class?

Comment: It's Framework3.5 so no WCF :)

Comment: .NET 3.5 does have WCF, are you trying to use an asmx web service?

Comment: Yes.. and I cannot use WFC. I have to do it "old fashion way". I user C# Web Service in Visual Studio 2010. Client Application is WebApplication in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: So can you set your ASMX service properties to receive List<T>, cause you cannot transfer an interface (like IEnumerable<T>) through a soap serialization.

Comment: You mean:         [WebMethod]
        public List<Transaction> getTransactions(int client_id)
        {
            BankDataLINQDataContext DB = new BankDataLINQDataContext();
            return (from u in DB.Transactions where u.ClientID == client_id select u).ToList() ;
        }  <-it's generate query list result, but I cannot get it in Client Application (at least I don;t know how) :/

Comment: Can you post the exact error/exceptions you are getting?

Comment: 1)  You shouldn't be using ASMX, and 2) Even if you're using ASMX, you can use "Add Service Reference" on the client.

Comment: I have Web reference on the client, and It's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!

Side of WebService:

```
    [WebMethod(Description="Pobranie operacji z konta bankowego")]
    public List<Transaction> GetTransactions(int clientID)
    {
        BankDataLINQDataContext DB = new BankDataLINQDataContext();
        List<Transaction> ListOfTrans = (from u in DB.Transactions  
                                      where u.ClientID == clientID 
                                      select u).ToList();

        return ListOfTrans;

    }
```

side of client of WebService:

```
        List<Transaction> ListToView = getalltransactions.GetTransactions(ClientID).ToList();
        GridView1.DataSource = ListToView;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

I hope that this solution will be useful for someone.
Thanks for all hints :)

Answer (score 0):

If your DataContext is setup like most Linq DataContexts, your query in parentheses will be typed as IQueryable<Transaction>. Assuming this is correct, you are trying to cast an IQueryable<Transaction> into an IEnumerable<DataRow>. Linq will not automatically figure out how to convert between a Transaction and a Datarow - you need to specify that yourself. So your code should probably look more like:

```
[WebMethod]
public IEnumerable<DataRow> getTransactions(int client_id)
{
    BankDataLINQDataContext DB = new BankDataLINQDataContext();
    var queryResults = (from u in DB.Transactions
                        where u.ClientID == client_id
                        select GetDataRow(u)).ToList();
    return query;
}

public static DataRow GetDataRow(Transaction transaction)
{
     // Convert to a DataRow
}
```

Edit: To specify what I think the problem is, you cannot implicitly/automatically convert an IEnumerable<T> into an IEnumerable<U> without selecting each individual member into the new Type.

Comment: 1. It didn't work. Validator gives me error on "select GetDataRow(u)"  error is: GetDataRow doesn't exists in current context". 2. How convert to a DataRow?

Comment: You have to actually write and implement a method called "GetDataRow" which I stubbed out. It's up to you to convert the object to a DataRow.

Comment: Why don't you just return the Transaction object instead of a DataRow? Linq/Webforms does a pretty good job of JSON-izing objects for consumption by javascript